# Where to put a large diagram in a thesis?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, graphics, appendix

I was wondering what is the most acceptable way of including a large diagram in my thesis.
The diagram takes up a full page and splits a paragraph.

Is this bad? 
Should I put the image/diagram in an appendix? 
If so, how should I point the reader to that appendix? Do I just give them the appendix number?
Or is it fine leaving it in the middle of a paragraph over two pages?

Comment: You can refer to "Diagram X on page Y" instead in your narrative.

Answer (score 5):

If the diagram needs to be

a) full page
 b) visible to the reader to understand the paragraph

then I would *not* put it in the appendix. Leave it where it is.

The important question for me would be: Why does the diagram has to split the paragraph? Can't you show the whole paragraph and the diagram before or after this paragraph?

I would not split the diagram over two pages, just to make that sure.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the same would apply to figures but, according to [Thesis and Assignment Writing](http://books.google.com/books/about/Assignment_and_thesis_writing.html?id=5Bq6AAAACAAJ) by Jonathan Anderson and Millicent Poole, a decision must be made whether to include tables in the body of the text or in an appendix.

They recommend that, if the material (a.k.a. figure) being presented is essential for the understanding of the argument, or essential for the conclusions that follow, it should be put in main body of the text, and preferably after its first reference.  If it consists of supporting material, it can be placed in an appendix.

The aim should always be to present a smooth flowing argument or thesis.